# [о]>[у] в "господарь">"государь" — единичный случай?

Tags: история-языка, фонетика

Известны ли, помимо `господарь`>`государь`, еще случаи (до распространения аканья, разумеется), когда [о] сужалось в [у]? Может быть, также связанные с выпадением согласного?

Comment: Чередования вроде **сохнуть - сухо** не подходят?

Comment: Нет, это другое. Там всегда были разные гласные.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One I can think of right away is *муравей < моровей < *морвии*.

Chernykh considers both words (*муравей* and *государь*) to be results of folk etymology rather than phonetic development.

Comment: Interesting! What are the folk etymologies though?

Comment: Wait, of course, `мурава`. And the other one? `Судить`?

Comment: @NikolayErshov: according to Chernykh, yes.